# angular -"changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity" gives ts error "Property 'changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity' does not exist on type 'SafeUrl'."

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my app I am displaying an image in this way-

```
loadProfileImage(userID){
    this.settingsService.getProfileImage(userID).subscribe((data) =>{
        if (data){
            this.profileImage = data;
            const imageBlobUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL( data ));
            this.profileImage = imageBlobUrl.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity;
        }
    });
}
```

All works good, when I debug I can see that the param imageBlobUrl is from type SafeUrlImpl and does have the field "changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity", but when I run production build I get this error "Property 'changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity' does not exist on type 'SafeUrl'", how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use that property, it's a private property. You should just assign the `SafeUrl` to your `profileImage`:

```
profileImage?: SafeUrl;

loadProfileImage(userID){
    this.settingsService.getProfileImage(userID).subscribe((data) =>{
        if (data){
            this.profileImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL( data ));
        }
    });
}
```

which you can use in your template like:

```
<img *ngIf="profileImage" [src]="profileImage">
```

<sub>note: you can also make use of a custom SafeUrl pipe which does this for you. In combination with the `async` pipe you make your code a lot smaller</sub>

Comment: Without this line, I get a security error in the console. you mean to write my own pipe?

Comment: Cannot GET /app/SafeValue%20must%20use%20[property]=binding:%20blob:http://localhost:4200/d2551335-2a83-4180-98dd-a466ce473999%20(see%20http://g.co/ng/security

Comment: sanitizing should be done automatically, and an ObjectURL should be safe. You can try to do it without the sanitizer

Comment: @danda what worked? :) no sanitizer, or using a pipe?

Comment: just to know- which pipe you referred?

Comment: @danda a custom SafeUrl pipe